# How to pass multiple inputs to a pipe segment in python?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, bioinformatics

I'm building a data pipeline where raw files are processed into binaries.  The files are large and there are multiple steps, so it is advantageous to avoid writing to disk when possible.  It is easy to take the output of one subprocess and make it the input of another, but how do I handle a subprocess that requires multiple input files? In particular:

I have two processes doing operations on two files, A and B, which output files A' and B'. The next command uses the following shell syntax

```
bwa sampe referencefile A' B' A B
```

requiring five files.  This can be done easily with `shell=True` if A' and B' are written to disk, but this is what I want to avoid.  How can I implement an stdout -> stdin relationship that avoids writing to disk, and maintains correct order?

Comment: If you're aligning paired end reads using BWA, your inputs are a consensus fasta, two index files, and two fasta files, and your output should be one .sam file. Why do you not want the .sam file? Do you want it converted directly to .bam? Are you trying to go from reads -> .sam -> .bam -> sorted.bam without writing to disk?

Comment: Edit: So you have two processes indexing your fasta files (A, B) which yield A', B'. Then you want to align with BWA to produce a .sam file. Why don't you want to save the indexes to file? You could always store them in `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`s which get cleaned up on script exit. Are you going to store your .sam file to disk? Also, why not use `bwa mem ref.fa in1.fa in2.fa > aln-pe.sam`? It removes the indexing step, creating them in memory, which is in effect what you are doing. You may need to update your BWA.

Comment: thanks a lot, I was unaware of both the tempfile and mem workarounds.  i tried both and they work

Answer (score 0):

'named pipe': does that bash command works with python ?

```
bwa sampe referencefile <(bwa aln ref fastq1)  <(bwa aln ref fastq2) fastq1 fastq2
```

you could also ask biostars.org